# Power of the Set

Tags: java

I generated all the subsequences of the array using recursion, but I can't figure out why my pow
(last line print statement) is printing null arraylist, while the powset print statement always prints the subsequence fine.
Is there a concept of pass by value / pass by reference ?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class recursion {
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> pow;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {2, 3, 5};
        int sum = 10;
        ArrayList<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<>();
         pow = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        powset(arr, 0, ans);
        System.out.println(pow);  // Prints empty arraylist everytime
    }

    private static void powset(int[] arr, int i, ArrayList<Integer> ans) {
        if(i >= arr.length){
            System.out.println(ans); // prints the correct arraylist as expected
            pow.add(ans);
            return;
        }
        ans.add(arr[i]);
        powset(arr,i+1,ans);
        ans.remove(ans.size()-1);
        powset(arr,i+1,ans);

    }


}
```

I was expecting the **pow** arraylist to print all the arraylist inside it, but It is printing empty arraylists.

Comment: you are adding and working on the SAME instance of the `List` -  adding an element to `pow` will NOT create a copy of it - if you remove (or add) items to `ans` you are also changing the instance that is inside `pow`

Comment: Just follow the logic of your code: you're adding elements to `ans` (via `ans.add(arr[i])`) and print them, then remove elements again (via `ans.remove(ans.size()-1)`)  and print that too. In the end you print `pow` which contains _several references to the same instance_ of `ans` which is empty at that point. - To make this clear: `ans` always refers to the same instance and thus `pow.add(ans)` adds a reference to that instance to `pow` again and again.

Comment: If you hook a debugger up, you can easily see the state of each variable as you proceed through your code.

Answer (score 2):

Count the `new`. I count exactly 2 `new` statements executed for the *entire* run: `ans = new ArrayList<>()` and `pow = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>()`.

That means there are 2 lists and only 2, **total**.

> Is there a concept of pass by value / pass by reference ?

All non-primitives **are** references in java. When you write `ans = new ArrayList<>()`, that is **not** stating that ans *is* the list. It is short for:

- Find a place on the beach (the heap).
- Conjure a new arraylist and bury it here, in this place on the beach.
- Draw a map *to* this place on the piece of paper named `ans`.

When you pass 'ans' to another method, it's pass by value, i.e., a copy, but you're copying the treasuremap. Not the treasure. So if the called method uses `=` (that's java-ese for: Wipe out the treasure map and draw a new map), the caller doesn't notice anything (their copy of the map isn't being wiped, after all). But if the called method uses `.`, such as `.add` or `.remove`, well, `.` is java-ese for: Follow the map and dig down. Even though you have a copy of the treasure map, given that it leads to the same treasure, if someone else digs down and messes with the treasure, you'd notice.

Thus, **count the `new`**. If you expect your code to produce 15 arraylists, then throughout its total execution, exactly 15 `new` statements need to be executed.

`new ArrayList<>(someList)` makes a clone.